# NameError: name 'htmltext' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

I obtain an error when i run this script:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://nytimes.com,http://nytimes.com"

urls = [url] #stack of urls to scrape
visited = [url] #historic record of urls

while len(urls) >0:
try:
    htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
except:
    print(htmltext)
```

Original scipt:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://nytimes.com,http://nytimes.com"

urls = [url] #stack of urls to scrape
visited = [url] #historic record of urls

while len(urls) >0:
try:
    htmltext = urllib.request.urlopen(urls[0]).read()
except:
    print(urls[0])
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)

urls.pop(0)

print (soup.findAll('a',href=True))
```

Errors:

> socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>
> urllib.error.URLError: urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> NameError: name 'htmltext' is not defined

Comment: Well what happens if you put `http://nytimes.com,http://nytimes.com` into your browser address bar? Also, your title does not match the description (but *of course* `htmltext` isn't defined in the `except` case - you're there because the assignment *failed*).

Comment: i dont know how it is possible but now is working, sorry

Comment: i understand why it worked, i removed the second address from "url" value, possible conflict during connection request because it was doubled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `urllib.request.urlopen()` raises an exception, `htmltext` never gets assigned a value (so printing that value in `except` won't work).

As to why `urlopen()` is not working, make sure you are passing a valid URL.

Comment: Thanks a lot! only now i understand the meaning of "try" and "except" :D